# Tess4j: how to get confidence that an image shows "x" character?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

Using Tess4j wrapper for Tesseract.

I want to know how close to a certain character an image is.

[image: example input image]

So, for example, I input the image above and ask tesseract "how close to the character 'G' is that image?" and it tells me from 0-1.

I don't want it to identify 'G' and tell me how confident it is. I want it to tell me how confident it is that the image is a 'G' regardless of the character it identifies.

Something like `float getConfidenceInCharacter(image, character)`.

The code I've found only shows confidence in a given answer, not confidence for a certain answer.